# Spring boot app with Embedded tomcat

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-boot, amazon-ec2

I am working on a project, we are using Spring-Boot, STS. I just start the project with right click on main and run as spring boot app and it simply runs. Now I am asked to run it with Embedded tomcat on some other machine like Amazon EC2 instance. 
In normal spring project what I used to do is, create a war file, place in tomcat->webapps folder and start it from bin. 
In case of embedded tomcat how would I run my app without tomcat. where will my war(which includes embedded tomcat dependencies) run?
Please suggest some solution, this is first time working with spring boot and embedded tomcat.
Appreciate your suggestion.

Comment: Where exactly are you required to run your app? Cloud services are able to run a jar file and you shouldn't worry about the embedded tomcat.

Answer (score 6):

It is suggested to built jar file for spring boot application. This jar contains embedded tomcat inside it. But ofcourse you can build it as war file too. For both of them to run you can simply run `java -jar your-jar-file.jar` or `java -jar your-war-file.war`

Answer (score 6):

Just pull in Spring boot tomcat starter, inside your pom or gradle build. This will bring all the tomcat dependencies to your app jar. Embedded tomcat means in runtime inside your JVM Spring boot starts a server with the dependencies in your jar. 
So all the problems of pushing the war to tomcat folder and restarting are eliminated.
Build your jar using Spring boot plugin. mvn spring-boot:run or gradle bootRun and then just run this jar as any executable jar.

```
java -jar your-app.jar
```

This calls the Spring Boot Main class. Which internally starts your server and creates your application context.
This works for all platform, your local or EC2.

Answer (score 3):

First, let me clarify about `war` and `jar` in the context of modern java web application development.

In the distant past, applications were written, packaged into `.war` files and deployed onto `tomcat` servers which ran on some OS like Linux. Usually these applications were big and reflected the whole business logic of some `service`, like a library site, which wholly depended on this one application that treated requests by generating a suiting response for each one of them.

With time, the web got bigger: `More users + more data + stronger computers = more traffic`. It got hard to keep this model of application development because It failed to serve reliably under high throughput traffic.

That's how [Microservices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microservices) were born. To keep a long story short:
In Java, the best way to build microservices is by using `spring-boot` and the best way to deploy microservices is by using an embedded server for each microservice, like `tomcat`. Then these microservices are ideally deployed to the cloud (like `AWS`). Cloud services know how to deal with `jars` because jars are native to them.

Now, to your question, where will your war run? Your war won't run. Your jar will be executed by a cloud service and because It has an embedded tomcat dependency, It will run tomcat which will listen on default port `8080`. This will be the gateway to your application that you built. The cloud service will probably allocate some `DNS` to your application and you will be able to communicate with It's embedded `tomcat` that way.

Comment: This is false.  Servlet containers were always designed to accommodate clustering.  It’s built into the Servlet specification and it’s built into the Java EE specification.  That is literally what the first ‘E’ in Java EE stands for:  “Enterprise Edition” refers to software that is capable of scaling to millions of users or tasks.  Spring “microservices” are not a new concept; they’re just a clumsy, naive approach to something that already existed.

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to jar using your IDE you are using..

Then :

***On Windows, you have to set the java.exe(with full path) in the environment variable(with variable name = java). and then you can run*** `java -jar "jar name with the full path"`

**If path is not set then what you have to do is :**
Example :

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\bin\java.exe" -jar "jar name with the full path"
```

**- it will work 100% - check it out**

thanks **:)**